# How can I enable DGRM configurator in cooja?

Tags: contiki

As explained for bidirectional links in http://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/RPL_objective_function_%26_simulation_using_DGRM_model_in_cooja

I am using contiki 2.7 and I could not find Tools−−> DGRM configurator. Can anyone please help in steps on how to enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry only shows up after creating a simulation model using DGRM. If this is not the case, you must give more information about which version of Cooja you are using.

Comment: But I think for creating the bidirectional links in simulation model, DGRM is needed. Is it not so? I am using cooja 2.7 version.

Comment: Yes. Are you sure you selected the DGRM when setting up the simulation? Also the entry is now called "DGRM links...". Otherwise I'm unable to reproduce your problem.